# reenable onclick behavior after preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I disable a click event on my element in one point how can I later can re-enable again?

```
$(myElem).click(function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: use `.on()` and `.off()` to enable disable events.

Comment: Once you call `preventDefault()` you have cancelled the event, you cannot 're-enable' it. You should change your logic flow so that `preventDefault()` is only called when required.

Comment: please provide with example

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<button id="test" >test</button>
```

Js:

```
$('#test1').click(function (e){
   if($(this).hasClass('prevented')){
       e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

You can also use eg. data-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(myElem).click(function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });    
$(myElem).unbind('click');
```

Comment: what is it? How this is enabling the event again?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know, if this is the best solution, but its an easy one: set a flag outside the "click scope" ...

```
var pd = true;

$(myElem).click(function (event) { 
  if (pd) event.preventDefault(); 
  // other actions
});
```

Then you could later set pd = false. If pd is defined outside the click handler, this should work in my opinion.